# How to logout using facebook sdk in windoows phone app

Tags: c#, windows, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8

I am using Facebook sdk to integrate Facebook in my app. I have used Login button to log in into Facebook which redirects me to Facebook Login page automatically, means by providing your `appId`. But the problem is that when I click on Logout button it successfully logs me out of the app but when I click on Login button again it doesn't ask for any user login and password (it doesn't redirect me to Facebook Login page, but directly redirects to my apps home page).

How to destroy all cache/session info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not using Facebook SDK API. Facebook proposes,

> Windows Phone apps must create their own way of storing when a person
>   has logged in, and when that indicator is not there, proceed on the
>   assumption that they are logged out. If someone is logged out, then
>   your app should redirect them to the Login dialog at an appropriate
>   time — for example if they click a Login button.

This [Official page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone) might throw more light on it.

Basically, you need to have a flag stored somewhere in Isolated storage, that can be set to rue of false as and when user logs in and out...and redirect him to login.

Well, on a lighter note, its not less known fact that Facebook Logout button is a hardest button to find.. :) Hope this helps...